# Removed a VHDX disk from VM and after readding it my data has reset to 4+ months ago?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, vhdx

I have a HyperV server with a VM for a windows file share. I have a VHDX attached to the VM that has all the data for the file share. I needed to temporarily remove the VHDX disk, and upon clicking "Remove" it prompted me to create a checkpoint to avoid data loss:

[image]

I clicked "Create Checkpoint and Continue" and I have a checkpoint from that time.

After reattaching my VHDX file, I'm missing months of data. The latest file I have in there is from November 2022, but some folders are missing data going back a year. I'm very confused.

I am new to HyperV and clearly don't understand how checkpoints in Windows works. What did I do wrong and how can I prevent this in the future. Luckily I have a separate backup from 2 days ago but I want to know why this happened and how to not get myself into this situation again.

Looking at my virtual disk storage, I have a few MRT/RTC and AVHDX files from today, everything else is from November.

[image]

I use Veeam as a backup and thought it created checkpoints every time it ran a backup, but the last recovery checkpoint was from November 15th 2022. In the checkpoints list, I removed the disk at the 12:43PM checkpoint.

[image]

Did I truly lose the data or am I missing something?

Comment: A new exemplar for not using Checkpoints in production. This is an accident waiting to happen, and leads to situations such as this.

Comment: Thats what I'm learning lol. Really glad I recently upped my backup game so it was only a minor inconvenience. I believe Veeam Backup needs to make checkpoints, but thats something I'll have to look into more. Clearly not doing what I thought it was though as the last Recovery checkpoint from Veeam was in November.